# Square root of a positive real analytic function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request

Let $f(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a positive real analytic function of $x$. My question is, how can I prove or disprove that $g(x) := \sqrt{f(x)}$ is also real analytic? I am new to this stuff, and my definition of real analytic functions is something that has a Taylor series expansion. However, I am having trouble implementing this definition on $g(x)$ directly. Is there any other way to check real analyticity? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I think I have an idea: from Andres Caicedo's answer on this MSE [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590455/how-to-check-the-real-analyticity-of-a-function?rq=1), we know that the composition of real analytic functions is real analytic.
So, we can write $$\sqrt{f} = e^{\text{log}(\sqrt{f})} = e^{\frac{1}{2}\text{log }f}.$$
I think this solves the problem?

Comment: To be a completely correct solution, you should add something like: The function $\sqrt x$ is analytic on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Solution by @novice has a lack: we must require that ln f(x) is analytic, which does not hold for, e.g., f(x)=x at x=0.